# Visual Studio and MS Excel Date in function

Tags: c#, excel, date

I write some dates from my VS Form to Excel. 
In the first moment i thought all is fine but there is a problem.
The date format is used - check
The information is the same - check (VS to MS)
Can use the cell in function - NOT =/

to solve this I go in Excel, enter the cell und press enter. -> all fine -.-

VS snipping

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

 ...

 //Date
 ws.Cells[j, 2].Value = date;
```

---

MS snipping

[When it would be right the october shows the 25th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVDxT.png)

Any ideas? Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

after one hour I found a button for "show funcion" in MS Excel.
Now I see the Problem:

31.07.2013  -> false
41487       -> true

so i will check my VS Programm and Transmit an INT , not a String

Comment: This is not the solution. You can either transmit a Date if the Excel cell has a Date type (and both C# type and Excel have the same format); or transmit a String if the Excel cell type is Text. You should post your conditions more clearly (date formats, sample input and the result you get, etc.) if you want to get a proper answer.